# Proper location for software on non-boot partition

Tags: directory-structure

I've got a computer that boots off an SSD, with an HDD for miscellaneous user data (currently, my `/home` partition).

I want to move some installed software from `/usr/local/bin` to a directory on the HDD, to save space on the SSD for things where the improved loading time is more significant (and also save wear on the SSD).

Is there a standard place to put that sort of thing, or should I just come up with something myself and add it to my `PATH`/symlink it into `/usr/local/bin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard having rules or recommendations for this situation, however it is fairly common so well worth discussing.

Firstly, I would avoid symlinks. In my opinion it is usually much cleaner to modify the path. Using either `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile` is probably best.

As for directory structure, I would recommend something along the lines of `local/` (`/mnt/hdd/local/bin` for example). This would be consistent with using `$HOME/.local` as a user software prefix and `/usr/local` as a sysadmin's custom/non-distro software prefix.

As for only installing the binaries, for [most software](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html) that would be a case of setting `exec_prefix=/path/to/local/`. For other software, you would need to look at their specific build documentation.